# Are 0=='' and '0'=='' same?

Tags: php, equals

Consider the following PHP statements:

```
echo ( 0  == '' ? 1 : 0); // Output is 1
echo ('0' == '' ? 1 : 0); // Output is 0
```

The first will print 1, and the second will print 0. Shouldn't they both print 0? Is this expected behavior? I'm guessing its because the second is a string and the first is not, but I'd like another answer.

Answer (score 6):

Read  **Loose comparisons with `==`**

### http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 3):

In Php empty string, NULL and 0 are equal.
In second case `'0'` is another string, and `''` is another. So you get result false.

`"", 0, "0", False, array(), Null` are all considered False in PHP.

You can use `===` to make them different.

Comment: empty string, NULL, 0 and false are the same!

Comment: This is a misleading answer! Yes, all these are considered *`false`*, but `false` requires a *boolean context*. I.e. `if (null)` or `null == false`. That doesn't apply to a direct comparison to a non-boolean value. According to your answer *both* cases should result in `1`, which they don't.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. It's some kind of misspelling. I think our answer are equal, I mean same as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct behavior. `0` is equal to empty string as well as to `false`/`null`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the first line is not comparing two variables of the same type:

```
echo ( 0  == '' ? 1 : 0); // Output is 1
echo ('0' == '' ? 1 : 0); // Output is 0
```

Observe the following:

```
echo ( 0  === '' ? 1 : 0); // Output is 0
```

The `===` operator does a type sensitive equality check, which seems to be what you are expecting. `==` will do a bit of a fuzzy check if the two arguments are not of the same type.

You should check out the [comparison operators documentation](http://php.net/operators) for more information:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is interpreting both the 0 and the empty string as "false" and they are coming out as equal. PHP has lots of quirks around what it will interpret as true/false.
The second is comparing the string '0' to a blank string and coming up with unequal.

To make sure you compare actual values you should use the === comparison

Answer (score 1):

0 == '' == null

but '0' is a string.

You'd better use **===** to check the difference of 0, '0', null

```
php > var_dump(0);
int(0)
php > var_dump('0');
string(1) "0"
php > var_dump(null);
NULL
php > var_dump('');
string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the comparison logic here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
Type of Operand 1    Type of Operand 2    Result

null or string       string               Convert NULL to "", numerical or lexical comparison

string, resource     string, resource     Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math
or number            or number
```

That means for `'0' == ''`, the first case applies, and *lexical comparison* is used. And "0" and "" are not equal according to lexical comparison.

For `0 == ''`, the second case applies. `''` is converted to a number, `0` in this case, which is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`'0' == ''` will always be false. Because symbol `'0'` is not an empty symbol. But in PHP 0 (zero) and empty symbol are the same.